# Update postgres row where condition is from another table

Tags: postgresql, update

I want to update a password field from a given value that exists from another table.

**user_info:**

```
--------------------------------------------
| user_login | password                    |
|------------|-----------------------------|
| ad         | $2a$12$oGBdoD....ia9mk25OHu |
--------------------------------------------
```

**user_contacts**

```
-------------------------
| user_login | email    |
|------------|----------|
| ad         | ad@...com|
-------------------------
```

I would like to change the password by identifying the user_login using the associated email address. So, something like:

```
UPDATE user_info SET password = '$2a$11$fwea...IEI' WHERE user_contacts.email = 'ad@...com';
```

Would anyone have an idea how to go about this? I've been trying to search for an answer online, but I've either not been able to find anything relating to this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this can be solved relatively quickly, by adding a `FROM` clause to your `UPDATE`, and adding an additional equality condition, namely, adding `user_info.user_login = user_contacts.user_login`.

```
UPDATE user_info SET password = '$2a$11$fwea...IEI' 
FROM user_contacts
WHERE user_info.user_login = user_contacts.user_login
AND user_contacts.email = 'ad@...com';
```

This will almost certainly do what you are asking.

Refer to the **[PostgreSQL Documentation on `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html)** for more info.